# Find all possible combinations of letters from two "alphabets" for any given word

Tags: java, math, logic

I got these two arrays of "alphabets":

```
private static final char[] regularAlphabet = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z' };
private static final char[] secondAlphabet = {'ᴀ', 'ʙ', 'ᴄ', 'ᴅ', 'ᴇ', 'ꜰ', 'ɢ', 'ʜ', 'ɪ', 'ᴊ', 'ᴋ', 'ʟ', 'ᴍ', 'ɴ', 'ᴏ', 'ᴘ', 'q', 'ʀ', 'ꜱ', 'ᴛ', 'ᴜ', 'ᴠ', 'ᴡ', 'x', 'ʏ', 'ᴢ' };
```

secondAlphabet uses special characters so they are read differently to regular ones.

What I intend to do is print all the possible combinations that could be done for a given string. For example, given the String "ab" we can get: `ab, ᴀb, aʙ, ᴀʙ` (mind the difference in the characters pulled from each "alphabet").

The word will stay the same so the letters would not be rearranged, it's just about finding every possible mix between these types of letters for that word. Also, using methods such as toUpperCase wouldn't work cause I need to use these special characters found in secondArray.

What kind of loop would I need to find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

### **Edit:** Not the right answer

You might be able to use a double for-loop like so:

```java
for (char ch1 : regularAlphabet) {
    for (char ch2 : secondAlphabet) {
        System.out.println(String.valueOf(ch1) + String.valueOf(ch2));
    }
}
```

Or better yet, an optimized for loop (less readable)

```java
for (int i = 0; i < regularAlphabet.length * secondAlphabet.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(String.valueOf(regularAlphabet[i % regularAlphabet.length]) + String.valueOf(secondAlphabet[(int) (i / regularAlphabet.length)]));
}
```

Comment: I want to be able to input any word and get all possible combinations of letters for it from both alphabets, not simply get all 2 letter combinations

Comment: oh sorry, I misunderstood.